# Should I configure sessionManagement in HttpSecurity if I use Spring Session?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-session

I am trying to understand how Spring Security and Spring Session projects work together.
In my project I want to save sessions into database that's why I am using Spring Session JDBC. But I can't understand should I configure something in
`@Bean public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)`
in part `sessionManagement`. For example I've tried to set maximum user sessions by

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .sessionManagement(session -> session
            .maximumSessions(1)
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

and there is no affect. Can someone explain why there is no affect and should I configure sessionManagement in HttpSecurity ?

Comment: No, you do not need to mess about with filters. This is all you need to do - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-session-jdbc